# Logic problems with AngularJS and multiple $http queries

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angular-resource

I have an app that will make 2 $http queries to an external API and get 2 different JSON responses. These responses will populate a ng-repeat, headers, etc. 
My problem is that I want to include a 3rd query, dependent on the first two.

Like so:

I get artist JSON and release JSON, and I use artist.name and release.title to populate the URL of the third $http query.

So far I've managed to get the two first queries, and once the results they are displaying in the ng-repeat, with ng-click I launch the 3rd query and populate an img ng-src.

Buuut, my problem is that I want the img ng-src to be populated automatically without ng-click, so the function that triggers the 3rd query has to get launched right after the 2 first queries. And also, in my working version right now, the img that I fetch with ng-click, will populate all items in ng-repeat. Meaning that every item should get their own image, and right now they don't.

I've created a [working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gRWmPc89wnUKT0YH5fUs?p=preview), if you search for a music artist and click on a result and then on an album, you'll see what I mean.

Basically, I think I'm missing a piece of logic that will put everything together and in proper trigger order.

Any thoughts?

My JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource'])

  function Ctrl($scope, $http) {
    var search = function(name) {
      if (name) {
        $http.get('http://api.discogs.com/database/search?type=artist&q='+ name +'&page=1&per_page=5').
          success(function(data3) {
            $scope.clicked = false;
            $scope.results = data3.results;
          });
      }
      $scope.reset = function () {
        $scope.sliding = false;
        $scope.name = undefined;
      }
    }
    $scope.$watch('name', search, true);

    $scope.getDetails = function (id) {
      $http.get('http://api.discogs.com/artists/' + id).
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.artist = data;
        });
      $http.get('http://api.discogs.com/artists/' + id + '/releases?page=1&per_page=100').
        success(function(data2) {
            $scope.releases = data2.releases;
        });
      $scope.clicked = true;
      $scope.sliding = true;
      $scope.getImages = function (title, name) {
        $http.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=e8aefa857fc74255570c1ee62b01cdba&artist=' + name + '&album='+ title +'&format=json').
          success(function(data4) {
              $scope.images = data4;
          });
      }
    }


  };
```

My directive:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource'])

 .directive('artistData', function() {

      return{
          restrict: 'E',
          template: '<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2"> \
                     <h1 ng-show="artist.name" class="artist-name">{{artist.name}}</h1>  \
                     <div class="header-border" ng-show="artist.name"></div> \
                     <input ng-show="artist.name" class="form-control" ng-model="album" /> \
                      <div class="col-md-3" ng-click="getImages(release.title, artist.name)" ng-repeat="release in releases | filter:album | filter:{ role: \'main\' }"><div class="release">{{release.title}}<img class="img-responsive" ng-src="{{images.album.image[2][\'#text\']}}" /></div></div> \
                     </div>',
          replace: true
      };
    })
```

And my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
      <div class="intro">

        <div class="intro-text" ng-class="{'slide':sliding}">
          <h1>Howdy stranger!</h1>
          <h3>Use the form below to search for an artist and start building your record collection!</h3>
        </div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="name" class="form-control input-lg" ng-class="{'slide':sliding}" ng-focus="reset()" placeholder="Artist name"/>
      </div>
      <ul ng-hide="clicked" class="search-results">
        <li ng-repeat="result in results" ng-click="getDetails(result.id)">{{result.title}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <artist-data></artist-data>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use "Chaining Promises" in this case.

In basic words you call new async task on response of previous.

[image]

You can read this <kbd>[POST](http://urish.org/angular/AngularPromises.pdf)</kbd> that might help you

Comment: Ill look into it as soon as Im home. Thanks Maxim!